# Mac El Capitan and Mamp Pro 4.1 won't run MySQL

Tags: mysql, macos, mamp, mamp-pro

I've run into an issue that has me totally stumped. A little preface here - I'm not a MySQL guy. I know enough to get around in MAMP and a little through the terminal but that's the extent of my knowledge.

I recently upgraded to MAMP PRO 4.1 (I'm on Mac OS 10.11.6) and I've been pulling out my hair ever since. It won't run MySQL and the error log is returning this.

```
170123 18:52:07 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
2017-01-23 18:52:07 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2017-01-23 18:52:07 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
2017-01-23 18:52:07 0 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.34) starting as process 13145 ...
2017-01-23 18:52:07 13145 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql56/ is case insensitive
2017-01-23 18:52:07 13145 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
2017-01-23 18:52:07 13145 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
2017-01-23 18:52:07 13145 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2017-01-23 18:52:07 13145 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2017-01-23 18:52:07 13145 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2017-01-23 18:52:07 13145 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2017-01-23 18:52:07 13145 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2017-01-23 18:52:07 13145 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-01-23 18:52:07 13145 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2017-01-23 18:52:07 13145 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-01-23 18:52:07 13145 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-01-23 18:52:07 13145 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 57680420515
2017-01-23 18:52:07 13145 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2017-01-23 18:52:07 13145 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2017-01-23 18:52:07 13145 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2017-01-23 18:52:07 13145 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2017-01-23 18:52:07 13145 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 57680420525
2017-01-23 18:52:07 13145 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-01-23 18:52:07 13145 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.34 started; log sequence number 57680420525
2017-01-23 18:52:08 13145 [Note] RSA private key file not found: /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql56//private_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
2017-01-23 18:52:08 13145 [Note] RSA public key file not found: /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql56//public_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
2017-01-23 18:52:08 13109 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 35
2017-01-23 18:52:08 13109 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.
2017-01-23 18:52:09 13109 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 35
2017-01-23 18:52:09 13109 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.
23:52:09 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=262144
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 134277 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x7f91330cda00
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 7fff590196d0 thread_stack 0x40000
0   mysqld                              0x0000000107131878 my_print_stacktrace + 72
1   mysqld                              0x0000000106df6fe8 handle_fatal_signal + 952
2   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff9580b52a _sigtramp + 26
3   mysqld                              0x0000000107b62c38 LOCK_plugin + 0
4   mysqld                              0x000000010701c223 _Z9get_fieldP11st_mem_rootP5Field + 99
5   mysqld                              0x0000000106e1d2d5 _ZL8acl_loadP3THDP10TABLE_LIST + 1941
6   mysqld                              0x0000000106e1c5b0 _Z10acl_reloadP3THD + 1264
7   mysqld                              0x0000000106e1c025 _Z8acl_initb + 405
8   mysqld                              0x000000010705b029 _Z11mysqld_mainiPPc + 2281
9   mysqld                              0x0000000106be7c22 main + 34
10  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff985a45ad start + 1

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (0): is an invalid pointer
Connection ID (thread ID): 0
Status: NOT_KILLED

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

I've tried to do my due diligence and killed all the mysqld processes and tried restarting again via:

```
ps aux | grep mysqld
sudo kill <process id of mysqld here>
```

However, the process id no longer exists by the time I run it. It's constantly starting, crashing, and trying to restart. Any help here would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and fixed it as follows:

1. Exit MAMP
2. In terminal run `killall -9 mysqld`
3. Start MAMP

If this doesn;t work, try putting `sudo` at the start of the terminal command.

See http://twob.net/journal/fix-for-mamp-mysql/ for more detailed info